# flex align-items center is not centering

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I have a code - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MQjpBG

It's a simple list with a colored block and text in each li

I need the list to be vertical and the text and block to be vertically aligned.

I'm trying to do this with flex and align-items but the text and block never center exactly

Am I doing something wrong, is there a better way to do this.

```
.element{
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;

  &__item{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 10px;

    &:last-of-type{
      margin-right: 0;
    }

    &-square{
      background: red;
      //display: block;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
    }

    &-text{
      font-weight: bold;
    }

  }

}
```

I want the block and text to fit like so.

[image]

The `align-items: center;` seems to do it but its slightly off, like

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing centering them (in your codepen).

Add this to your code:

```
.element{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* horizontal alignment */

.element__item {
    display: flex;           /* nested flex container */
    align-items: center;     /* vertical alignment */
}
```

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KQgmqr)

Comment: Sorry I'm getting my terms mixed up. I want the block the text vertically aligned which is why I was using `align-items: center;`. In your revised code pen the block and text aren't aligned vertically correctly

Comment: @ttmt Out of curiosity, my answer already does that, and with the _square/text_ aligned, which can't be done in any other way than what I posted, and if mine didn't do it how you want, what did I miss?

Comment: LGSon, I have updated the question with an image, probably should have done that originally

Comment: That's exactly what I have in my original answer. You just need to add margins for spacing. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gvwXzE

Comment: @ttmt Michael's initial answer does that, and for the items to also vertical center in the browser/viewport, the `element` need a height...and zero its padding/margin as well: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eVdVZX

Comment: Michael_B I know your code should do that but its not vertically in the center. I have updated the question again.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it looks like the issue is a function of the font chosen. Different fonts will have different descender heights (e.g. the tail of a "g") as well as different positioning of the base line relative to the full text box, and it appears that some fonts will have these values set such that they may not be visually centered.

I modified your CodePen example and forcibly set the `font-family` of the first element to Arial while leaving the second as the default (on Firefox on macOS 10.15/Catalina), and the Arial version definitely looks much more vertically centered:

[image]

You may be able to fix this by changing the font used, but obviously this isn't a change that can be made lightly on a large codebase.

Comment: Indeed, it was a font issue in my case also. +1

Answer (score 0):

To make the list to be vertical, just add "flex-direction"

```
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  flex-direction: column;
```

Answer (score 0):

For horizontally center aligned:

```
.element {
justify-content: center;
}
```

For vertical center alignment of squares and text:

```
.element__item-square {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.element__item-text {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```